# How to disable middle mouse button calling Instant Viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, mouse

I am using middle mouse button to rotate 3D scene in blender.

Unfortunately, sometimes, for some reason, Windows intercepts my clicks as some gesture or may be just as single middle-click and displays me all the windows in a grid to switch between applications.

This is very annoying.

Where it can be set? How to disable this behavior? I have Microsoft mouse and it is set as

[image]

I.e. no any action like "show me all applications running" or something. It is set somewhere else.

I found, that parasitic function is named "Instant Viewer". How to disable uninstall Instant Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

From acer's website, removing InstantViewer:

1. Click Start and type RegEdit in the search box.
2. In the Registry Editor, click the + sign next to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.`
3. Click the + sign next to `Microsoft` and, then, next to `Windows`.
4. Click the + sign next to `CurrentVersion` and, then, next to `Uninstall`.
5. Click `InstallShield_{5C4F9F4E-11AB-42CA-A034-5F519B073E80}`.
6. On the right side of the window, double-click `NoRemove 0x00000001 (1)`.
7. In the window that opens, type `0` to change `1` to `0`.
8. Click OK and restart the system.

Comment: I don't have this tab, I have Microsoft Mouse with separate setup window. Also, I don't want to disable middle button, I just want it to be middle button and nothing more.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to remove instantviewer.

Comment: you don't need to describe each folder level in a separate step, it's even much less readable

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the app-specific settings, then **ADD NEW**, choose "blender", and then change Wheel button to Middle-click. It is the settings i'm using for blender.

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific where to find this setting. Is it a setting of the Microsoft mouse driver?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that you can change app-specific settings in the "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" program.  The Windows site mentioned having to install this program, but my machine came with it loaded.  I just searched "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" in the search charm.  I was able to add an app-specific setting for the wheel-click to act as a middle-click instead of the "instant viewer".  Hope you have the same luck.